# Get records within range and overlapping records falling within range

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data:

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
1   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-01
2   | 2016-05-02 |  2016-05-25
3   | 2016-04-01 |  2016-06-01
4   | 2016-02-21 |  2016-06-01
5   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-06-01
===============================
```

My objective is to get all dates between 2016-05-01 and 2016-05-31
and any records that falls within May 2016

Thus the final result:

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
1   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-01
2   | 2016-05-02 |  2016-05-25
3   | 2016-04-01 |  2016-06-01
5   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-06-01
===============================
```

I was thinking of the following,

```
SELECT events_sysid, title, startdate, enddate, location, longlat, categoryid 
FROM events
WHERE 1=1 AND isactive = 1 AND userid = 2
AND (DATE(startdate) >= DATE('2017-05-01') AND DATE(enddate) <= DATE('2017-05-31'))
```

But this only yield;

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
1   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-01
2   | 2016-05-02 |  2016-05-25    
===============================
```

I've got lost on how to extract the "Any records that falls within May 2016"

Missing:

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
3   | 2016-04-01 |  2016-06-01
5   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-06-01
===============================
```

Comment: Of course you are only getting those two records, when you are demanding that the start date be greater-equal start of May _AND_ the end date be lesser-equal end of May. You want to select records that have either their start date _OR_ their end date fall into May.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find overlapping records with May, we are interested in those records that start before end of May and end after the start of May:

```
StartDate <= '2017-05-31' AND EndDate >= '2017-05-01'
```

In other words, we are not interested in records that start after end of May and the records that end before the start of May:

```
NOT (StartDate > '2017-05-31' OR EndDate < '2017-05-01’)
```

Comment: That will not yield all the results where one of the dates is in May.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan It will. Please give a failing sample.

Comment: Example number 5 OP gave us: StartDate: `2016-05-01` EndDate: `2016-06-01`. Disregard the fact that he used different years in his example and his request, but the end date of that example falls outside May.

Comment: Your case passed the criteria I wrote: `2016-05-01 <= '2016-05-31' AND 2016-06-01 >= '2016-05-01'` equals `true`

Comment: You're right. My bad. But I think I spotted another thing, because OP's example record #3 starts before May and ends after May, but he doesn't want that to be in the results. So at least one of the dates has to be IN may. His wording may be a little bit hard, but that's apparently the result he expects.

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive, I also always think twice myself :) - Added some explanation to my response.

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry, yes, #3 should be included, since it is still active as its end date will fall June 2016, I have updated my question, please advise

Comment: @paulpolo This solution gives you those missing records as well. Maybe other criteria is limiting the results, try it without `1=1 AND isactive = 1 AND userid = 2`.

Comment: @Amir, how about if I would like to get records within May but data in db starts with April and ends in May/June and filter is startdate = 2016-05-02 and enddate = 2016-05-02 only 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple you need to yield any record which fall in may, so you need to check whether it was created before month end and it was ended any after start of may month

```
Date(startdate) < "2016-06-01 00:00:00" AND Date(enddate) > "2016-04-30 23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from

> My objective is to get all dates between 2016-05-01 and 2016-05-31 and
>   any records that falls within May 2016

that, in short you need to get the dates in May irrespective of they start or end in May.

So try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM `dateTable` 
WHERE `StartDate` >= '2016-05-01' OR `EndDate` <= '2016-05-31'
```

Comment: how about those beyond May, but started within May?

Comment: I think it will satisfy the condition in the first case where we check if start time is after May. When I checked with the sample you gave it was working. Can you verify from ur side?